# Form Submission with Python

Tags: python, mechanize

I have recently been messing with form submission and I was making a Python script to see if I could create Steam accounts through only entering the Captcha. For reference, the site I am submitting to is https://store.steampowered.com/join/. As shown by a mechanize request, the forms to fill are shown below:

```
<create_account POST https://store.steampowered.com/join/ application/x-www-form-urlencoded
<TextControl(accountname=)>
<SelectControl(choose_accountname=[*, , ])>
<PasswordControl(password=)>
<PasswordControl(reenter_password=)>
<TextControl(email=)>
<TextControl(reenter_email=)>
<HiddenControl(challenge_question=) (readonly)>
<TextControl(secret_answer=)>
<HiddenControl(captchagid=1009037421128850761) (readonly)>
<TextControl(captcha_text=)>
<HiddenControl(action=submit_agreement) (readonly)>
<CheckboxControl(i_agree_check=[on])>
<HiddenControl(ticket=) (readonly)>>
```

Almost everything seems to work, but I'm having a little trouble getting mechanize and urllib2 to properly submit the form. I'm sure that I'm just doing something small and simple wrong, but I have spent a long time trying to find this error. My current request is formulated in a few simple lines like so:

```
def submit_form(self, captcha_text):
    self.form["accountname"]=account_prefix+get_next_number()
    self.form["password"]=account_password
    self.form["reenter_password"]=account_password
    email = emails.pop()
    self.form["email"] = email
    self.form["reenter_email"] = email
    control = self.form.find_control("challenge_question")
    control.disabled = False
    control.readonly = False
    control.value = "NameOfSchool"
    self.form["secret_answer"] = secret_answer
    self.form["captcha_text"] = captcha_text
    self.form.find_control(id="i_agree_check").items[0].selected = True
    print urllib2.urlopen(self.form.click()).read()
    inc_account_number()
    resave_email_list(emails)
```

Most of this request is probably right and there are only a few lines I really deem suspicious. With `mechanize` I am trying to check the "I agree AND am 13 years of age or older" box with the line `self.form.find_control(id="i_agree_check").items[0].selected = True`. Based on some of my testing I think that that line might actually work, but the whole setting of the ReadOnly `challenge_question` portion is most likely bugged. For reference, that code segment is:

```
    control = self.form.find_control("challenge_question")
    control.disabled = False
    control.readonly = False
    control.value = "NameOfSchool"
```

The final possibility for failure of submission would be the submission method: `urllib2.urlopen(self.form.click()).read()`

If anyone has **ANY** ideas about what could be going wrong or even an alternative method to accomplish the task using Python, I would be very grateful. I have searched hard and failed. If you can, lend a hand!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fetch page `https://store.steampowered.com/join/` and search for regexp `<input type="hidden" id="captchagid" name="captchagid" value="(.+)">`.

Captcha URL will be `https://store.steampowered.com/public/captcha.php?gid=<gid>`.

Fetch `https://store.steampowered.com/join/createaccount/` with POST data:

```
    accountname=<name>&password=<password>&email=<email>&challenge_question=<question>&secret_answer=<secretansewer>&captchagid=<gid>captcha_text=<captch_text>&i_agree=1&ticket=&count=4
```

Comment: Will it really work with &count=4 every time? and how do I submit such a POST request?

Comment: @Paul urllib.urlopen(url, post_data)

Comment: I figured that out with a bit of searching. Apparently the count doesn't matter if you aren't reusing captchas. All is good! Thanks a bundle.